# Creating new product in magnolia shop module

Tags: magnolia

I installed magnolia shop module 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT on magnolia 5.3.8. Everything is working fine with sample-shop which comes with the module by default. Then I tried to create new shop following https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Shop+module tutorial and I created the shop and all the related properties attached to shop successfully. I also created a new “Shop home” page and new “Product category” pages under it. However when I try to add new product to my new shop it doesn’t list down any product categories to select. For the products in sample shop it displays correctly.

Is there any step I have missed when creating new products for new shop. 
Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question within the score defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the snapshot. Use released version.